# How to set up forward search: from .tex under Emacs to position .pdf under Okular

Tags: emacs, ubuntu, viewers, forward-inverse-search, okular

I edit .tex file under Emacs and view them with Okular.

I have already set up the backward search: from .pdf to .tex by pressing Shift+Left click on the .pdf file. The related part of .emacs file is here:

```lisp
(server-start)
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'TeX-PDF-mode) 

(defun pdf-with-okular ()
 (add-to-list 'TeX-output-view-style
 (quote ("^pdf$" "." "okular %o %(outpage)"))))

(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook 'pdf-with-okular t)
(setq TeX-view-program-list '(("Okular" "okular %o"))) 
(setq TeX-view-program-selection '((output-pdf "Okular") (output-dvi "Okular")))

(custom-set-variables
 '(LaTeX-command "latex -synctex=1")
 '(cua-mode t nil (cua-base))
 '(show-paren-mode t))
```

However, I do not see how to make "forward" search work. Someone says when we position somewhere in the .tex file, press <kbd>C-c C-v</kbd>, we could go to the corresponding location of .pdf file. But here, when I press <kbd>C-c C-v</kbd> it opens another okular and we are always on the first page of the .pdf file.

P.S. My whole [.emacs](http://paste.ubuntu.com/656661/).

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
okular --unique %o#src:%n%b
```

This is what I use and works fine. Should definitely not open another window with the `--unique` command so something else is up if that occurs. A similar solution is in link below but through the menus not in the `.emacs` file. Should just be able to use the command above with what you already have and should bring you to the `line(%n)` in the file when you run view or `C-c C-v`:

http://mathieu.3maisons.org/wordpress/how-to-configure-emacs-and-auctex-to-work-with-a-pdf-viewer

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately things became more complicated with TeX Live 2011. A temporary solution to make forward search work with Okular is described here:

https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=274294#c20

Works for me, hope it will do for you, too.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```c
(quote ("^pdf$" "." "okular %o %(outpage)"))))
```

I have

```c
(quote ("^pdf$" "." "okular --unique -p %(outpage) %o"))))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But C-c C-v still opens another okular and it does not locate to the right position...